# What do the dates mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

"A number of applicants will be selected for a preliminary interview by Jan 11, 2019 and short-listed applicants will be invited for a campus visit around Jan 20, 2019. The final decision would be made in early Feb 2019."

> (A) At the end of Jan 11, a number of applicants will be selected out, but the preliminary interview hasn't been conducted; search committee will send invitations to short-listed applicants on Jan 20, but campus visit will be conducted later
>
> (B) At the end of Jan 11, search committee will finish all preliminary interviews; short-listed applicants will come to the campus around Jan 20.

Which one (A or B) sounds more reasonable for a typical job search?

Comment: Preliminary interview is conducted online. They will not do online interview between Jan 12 and Jan 16 because some key faculty members will be out of town. So either online interview by Jan 11, or between Jan 17 and Jan 19.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question asks "what is reasonable for a job search", rather than asking about the use of English. If you want clarity, or are concerned about booking flights etc, I suggest you contact HR or admissions of the organisation directly.

Answer (score 1):

The second part regarding campus visit sounds unclear.

- "A number of applicants will be selected for a preliminary interview by Jan 11, 2019"

  - The applicants will be selected by Jan 11, 2019.
  - Preliminary interview will be conducted presumably between Jan 11 and Jan 20, but no exact date is mentioned.
- "short-listed applicants will be invited for a campus visit around Jan 20, 2019"

  - This could have two different meanings:
  - short-listed applicants will be invited around Jan 20, 2019 OR
  - campus visit will be conducted around Jan 20, 2019
- "final decision would be made in early Feb 2019"

To conclude, they select some applicants for the preliminary interviews by Jan 11. The preliminary interview presumably takes place between Jan 11 and Jan 20 and then shortlisted candidates will be invited around Jan 20.

Comment: Thanks. However, if they send invitations for campus visit on Jan 20, applicants may come to campus 10 days later (need to book flight tickets, etc.), only very few days left for final decision to be made...

Comment: @Jessie Apologies, upon further reading, it sounds unclear when the campus visit will be conducted.

Comment: If campus visit will be conducted around Jan 20, they need to finish preliminary interviews around 10 days or one week earlier, then they can't only select some applicants by Jan 11...

Comment: @Jessie They select some applicants for the preliminary interviews by Jan 11. The preliminary interview presumably takes place between Jan 11 and Jan 20 and then shortlisted candidates will be invited around Jan 20. That is what I interpret.